# flowtype rejects html import with ./listentry.html. Required module not found

Tags: html, flowtype

I'm importing some html markup in a es2015 app build using babel and webpack

```
import MARKUP from './markup.html';
```

but flowtype reports an error

```
./markup.html. Required module not found
```

I've already tried to add a mapper:

```
module.file_ext=.html
module.name_mapper.extension='html' -> 'interfaces.flow/HTMLFlowStub.js'
```

with the following stub:

```
// @flow
const emptyHTMLModule: string = '';
export default emptyHTMLModule;
```

but the error persists.

What's wrong and is is there a way in flowtype to debug this kind of problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incredibly simple solution: I just forgot to take away ignoring html files.

*.flowconfig*

```
[ignore]
; .*\.html
```